# How to use charts in Swift ViewController into objective c ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, charts, import

I Want to show the chart in Objective c File. Intially,I have imported the charts file which is in swift language.I am able to show barchart in a  BarChartViewController.swift.But i want to show a bar chart in my AnalysisViewController Which is of objective c File.

I have done Swift coding in BarChartViewController.swift.But Now i want to use the same chart that i have shown in BarChartViewController in a AnalysisViewController.I didn't get solution using that steps.

How to import Charts file in my AnalysisViewController?
[My Project Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk3n4.png)

Comment: By Bridging you can do this.

Comment: Please Go through my screen.Just simple i want to show the chart in my objective c file.AnyOne please upload the full code.coz i struck with this issue.not able to go further.Thanks in advance!!!!I have tried all the solutions which is given in stack overflow.Do not post the question link....